# Reference on Heegner points

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

I am a senior undergraduate. I have learned something about elliptic curves (GTM97, GTM106, and the first few chapters of GTM151), modular forms (GTM228, Shimura's *arithmetic theory of automorphic functions*) and class field theory (Neukirch's books). I hope that I can write something about Heegner points as my undergraduate thesis, but my advisor seems to think that my level is not high enough to learn such things. However, I still want to learn something about Heegner points. So can someone recommend me some books or notes about Heegner points, please? Thanks in advance.
By the way, I don’t know anything about p-adic uniformization. Are there any books or notes that I can read if I want to learn about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how you were able to read such high level books!? I am not familiar with this topic but here are some other nots may interest of you:

*Birch, Bryan*, [**Heegner points: the beginnings**](http://www.msri.org/communications/books/Book49/), Darmon, Henri (ed.) et al., Heegner points and Rankin (L)-series. Papers from the workshop on special values of Rankin (L)-series, Berkeley, CA, USA, December 2001. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-83659-X/hbk). Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications 49, 1-10 (2004). [ZBL1073.11001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1073.11001).

*Brown, M. L.*, [**Heegner modules and elliptic curves**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b98488), Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1849. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-22290-1/pbk). x, 517 p. (2004). [ZBL1146.11029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1146.11029).

And some videos that may help you:
[Heegner Points 1-2-3 by Francesc Castella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2OOgIctKLA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere help. But I am sorry that I eventually changed the topic of my graduation thesis : (

Comment: Two years have passed, I quitted from mathematics and become a student of statitics...

Comment: @123: Good luck. Try to not test all roads. Use others experiences instead,